# R Sequence to Sequence Prediction

Tags: r, keras, sequence, predict

I would like to predict a sequence to sequence with R. I am searching some advice or tips to perform it.
I have 6 inputs I want to predict 6 outputs.

```
[25;24;23;45;5;6] => [2;3;45;19;8;6]
[2;3;45;19;8;6] => ?;?;?;?;?;?
```

I have a training csv file the goal is to predict next sequence. I don't if I have to use LSTM or seq2seq for this non linear problem.

Comment: If the sequence are Lotto numbers, function sample() may be a benchmark hard to beat.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, lol, no is not Lotto numbers, I wanted to predict next DNA coverage for 6 genes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM Encoder Decoder is suitable to solve your problem. For more information, follow this blog tutorial for sequence to sequence modeling for prediction task.

[How to Develop an Encoder-Decoder Model for Sequence-to-Sequence Prediction in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/)

The tutorial is for python, however you may get the concept of modeling your sequence data.